# Why was "Microsoft Office Professional vs. Home and Business" closed/deleted

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

Just saw a sudden drop in reputation, and I would like to know why that question got closed?

Comment: Can you include a link? if your rep dropped, the post was deleted. your rep *remains* if the post was simply closed. Also, based on just the title, it sounds like it was *not* a constructive question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The question](https://superuser.com/questions/425702/microsoft-office-professional-vs-home-and-business) was closed as too localised due to the fact that it's one person weighing up whether or not to buy a package.

It was deleted in normal rounds because there were no votes to reopen or edits to make it not too localised to one person's business decisions in comparing the packages.

Comment: Alright, having said that... Is there any way that when a question gets closed, people who have answered or commented are alerted? Or should I open a new Meta discussion for it (presumably on Meta.SE)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-a-stack-exchange-notification-when-a-question-gets-closed